# Webstorm 7 Mac OSX won't create a Node.js Express App

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I've been trying to create a Node.JS app with the express framework in Webstorm 7. I keep getting the following error:

[image: error]

I suppose it has to do with permissions or the NPM route, thou I have no idea how to modify this in Webstorm.

NPM and NODE work just fine in the console, so I'm guessing this is Webstorm not finding or not being able to access the correct routes. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: run `sudo chown -R Omar ~/.npm` from terminal and see if the problem shows up again

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that the permissions for the `~/.npm` directory were abnormal (sometimes happens if you run `sudo npm install -g ...`).  Run

```
$ sudo chown -R Omar ~/.npm
```

from terminal in order to reset permissions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm still not fully understanding permissions in ox x and package managers. if somthing doesnt install i ofter sudo to install it not knowing why it works. I need a good tutorial on this stuff. Anyway, i had this exact problem and this fixed it so thanks.